# How can I run this Powershell script as a user?

Tags: powershell, permissions

I am trying to run the following script upon startup of my machine because I cannot get a service to start on startup. I can schedule it to run. The problem I am facing seems to be a user vs administrator issue.

This is for a Windows 7 machine with PowerShell 4.0. 
I have set the execution policy to unrestricted. 
When I try to run the script as the User I designated to have administrative privileges I see the following error.

[image]
When I right click the powershell icon, run as administrator the command works fine. 
The command is

```
 get-service -name "*vmauthd*" |start-service
```

Is it possible to run this as my user account?

**Solution** I was able to get this script to run on startup as I initially desired. I turned off UAC and set the execution policy to unrestricted. I am not sure if the UAC was the issue before but the script runs now. I created a cmd file with this in the code. I set the cmd file to run at startup using Windows Task Scheduler and set the task to run whether logged in or not.

PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"

PowerShell -Command "get-service -name "*vmauthd*" | start-service"

pause

[Here is an image of the cmd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CweR.png)

Comment: Are you sure the user has access to even see the service? Security-related services might have restrictive DACLs  (for a reason!)

Comment: PowerShell's execution policy doesn't let you bypass system security. Services still have permissions that restrict who can start and stop them.

Comment: To Frode F. The user can run the get-service command and see the service if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You want to do this with your user account, or you need just to run in "admin mode"?

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, I am trying to run the command as my user account. My goal is to have this script run automatically at startup, so I do not have to manually start the service ever single time I start the computer.

Comment: If you want that, just set the service for 'automatic' startup.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart. That is what I tried first, setting it through services. Even though it is set that way. It does not start at startup. That is why I have to manually start it.